# Octave function to convert BMP image to grayscale matrix on [-1,1]

Tags: image, matlab, octave

For a university assignment, we were given a MATLAB/Octave toolbox. This includes the following function which should, in theory, read a BMP file and convert it to a matrix, with all values in [-1,1] where -1 means white and 1 means black.

```
function In=loadCNN(filename)
  Img=double(imread(filename));
  if size(Img,3)==3
    Img=(Img(:,:,1)+Img(:,:,2)+Img(:,:,3))/3;
  end     
  In=((double(Img)/127.5)-1)*-1;
end
```

However it does not work correctly, returning a matrix with, for example, 0.99216 for white pixels on [this image: [image: binary image]](https://users.itk.ppke.hu/~marma/downloads/logic01.bmp)

Please help me write a function to do this. It should also work for colored BMPs, where it should be converted to grayscale first.

Comment: Are you sure this code behaves differently in MATLAB and GNU Octave?

Comment: You need to check what the scale of `Img` is before you do any scaling.

Comment: @juliohm Not sure. I don't have MATLAB. A friend tried it for me in MATLAB and he said it doesn't work there either.

Comment: Then you should remove the text "...on Octave it does not work..." from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for all bmp image...

```
function In=loadCNN(filename)
    Img=double(imread(filename));
    if size(Img,3)==3
        Img=mean(Img,3)/255;
    end
    In=2*Img-1
end
```